# How do I "debug" strange mp4 issues?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, adobe-premiere

I have a collection of MP4 files which have been recorded during a live stream. They play just fine in VLC (on Windows) but when I try to import them into Premiere Pro the programs just hangs. I thought that maybe there is some issue with the file format so I tried using ffmpeg to copy them over to new files by simply doing

```
ffmpeg -i commentator1.mp4 -c copy commentator1-fixed.mp4
```

The command runs and produces a file and the following output

```
ffmpeg version N-99697-g6fb2bdd Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/zetatwo/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/zetatwo/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/zetatwo/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --bindir=/home/zetatwo/bin --enable-gpl --enable-gnutls --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-libsrt
  libavutil      56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavcodec     58.111.101 / 58.111.101
  libavformat    58. 62.100 / 58. 62.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.102 / 58. 11.102
  libavfilter     7. 88.100 /  7. 88.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
[h264 @ 0x55b5fa2d5640] no frame!
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'commentator1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
  Duration: 03:48:14.43, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2670 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 2501 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'commentator1-cut.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    encoder         : Lavf58.62.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 2501 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 0x55b5fa84fa80] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: -6000, current: -6000; changing to -5999. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x55b5fa84fa80] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 2586000, current: 2586000; changing to 2586001. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x55b5fa84fa80] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 2586001, current: 2586000; changing to 2586002. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x55b5fa84fa80] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 3063000, current: 3063000; changing to 3063001. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x55b5fa84fa80] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 3381000, current: 3381000; changing to 3381001. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x55b5fa84fa80] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 3732000, current: 3732000; changing to 3732001. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=410832 fps=22838 q=-1.0 Lsize= 4468127kB time=03:48:14.36 bitrate=2672.8kbits/s speed= 761x    
video:4181003kB audio:268225kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.424778%
```

However when I play the new file in VLC the video is fine but the sound cuts out roughly every other second. The file can now be imported in Premiere Pro but it interprets it as an audio file only with no video.

- How should I interpret this output ffmpeg?
- What could be the cause of this?
- How can I get more details about the files to understand more about what's going on?
- Is there a good way to fix this? Should I re-encode the files completely? (I'd rather not since there's quite a lot of media)

Comment: Ca you share a short sample input file?

Comment: It turns out that the video file consisted of multiple sequential stream segments which had different resolutions and/or frame rates and I guess this is what caused the issue. I went back and re-exported the video as separate files, one per stream segment and now the issues are gone so while this doesn't really answer any of the questions I asked, this is no longer an issue.